# on add previous element getting replaced in ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

did debugging. I can clearly see after entryLogs.add(dl); in the value of entryLogs. the first data is replaced and a second has been inserted to the ArrayList.

what is happening is every time i enter new value it adds it in the ArrayList but replaces the the first entry to be same as the second entry. 
for example: 
I add A and onclick it adds A. 
again, add B and onclick it add B. 
but in the Arraylist  the value is [17/4/2014:20:29 B, 17/4/2014:20:29 B]

Please suggest what needs to be done.
Entire code can be found here: https://github.com/tirthoguha/DroidProject/blob/myDiary/src/com/example/s0217980_diary/Monday_fragment.java

```
entryLogs = new ArrayList<DiaryLogs>();

            timeText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.dateTimeEText);

            entryText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.diaryEntryEText);

            Button saveBtn = (Button) getView()
                    .findViewById(R.id.saveDiaryEntryBtn);
            saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    timeEntry = timeText.getText().toString();

                    entryEntered = entryText.getText().toString();

                    dl = new DiaryLogs(1, timeEntry, entryEntered);

                    entryLogs.add(dl);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the class `DiaryLogs.java` you declare the strings timeEntry and entryEntered as `static`

```
static String timeEntry;
static String entryEntered;
```

Remove the static modifier and you'll be fine. Static objects will have the same value for **any** instance of that class (and are accessible even without having an instance of it), so if you set the value in another object, every instance will use that value.

Comment: you are legend, my friend :)

Comment: fixed, that part.
But came into a new problem in first onClick in Monday_fragment it add the data to ArrayList. Second OnClik in Monday_fragment it takes to Monday_list_fragment where the list is shown. There is a button which brings it back to the Monday_fragment.
I debugged an seen, when i came back all the data in ArrayList is gone.
How to keep the ArrayList data not to clear out on coming back.
Codes here:
https://github.com/tirthoguha/DroidProject/tree/myDiary/src/com/example/s0217980_diary

Comment: You must explicitly store the state of the arraylist when you are changing orientation or activity, if you want to use that data later on. You could check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503836/how-to-save-custom-arraylist-on-android-screen-rotate to implement this. I know the link is about rotating screens, but the same thing is happening when you move away from the activity or fragment. Another option is to create a class that extends Application, and declare the arraylist there. The problem then is that all classes can access it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should remove the line 64

```
entryLogs = new ArrayList<DiaryLogs>();
```

and initialize the ArrayList on the line 22

```
ArrayList<DiaryLogs> entryLogs;
```

Maybe it helps :)

Comment: did according to what you suggested, but same result

Answer (score 0):

Put these two lines

timeText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.dateTimeEText);

```
        entryText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.diaryEntryEText);
```

in  @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
}

May this will help.